# ASP MVC4 Overload Get and Post not working for me

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hello to the community,

I'm trying to overload the `Login()` method in my project but it is not working. When I start the App the Get method is called and when 
I try to login the same `Get` Method is still called. The Login with Post is never called and I do not understand why. Please Help. Here is my Code

HomeController:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(USER model, String returnUrl)
{
}
```

RouteConfig

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );`
```

StartUpconfig

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
 {
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Login")
```

Web.config

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Login" timeout="2880" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"/>
    </authentication>
```

Login.cshtml`

```
section id="loginForm">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
```

Comment: Do you have nested forms in your view (e.g. your `Html.BeginForm()` is inside another `<form>` element)?

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: I figure out what the problem was. I Just remove this line 
<deny users="?" /> in authorization and now it is working. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

I figure out what the problem was. I Just remove this line 
`<deny users="?" />` in authorization and now it is working. Thank you for your effort.